# Why protected var is KProperty and public/private var is KMutableProperty?

Tags: kotlin

In each of the following cases I have some *mutable* `var` properties. According to Javadocs mutable properties are represented by `KMutableProperty` but in these examples `protected` property is represented by `KProperty` class. Why is that so?

```
class FooA {
    var publicProp: String? = null
    protected var protectedProp: String? = null
    private var privateProp: String? = null

    fun foo() {
        val a = ::publicProp
        val b = ::protectedProp
        val c = ::privateProp
    }
}

open class FooB {
    var publicProp: String? = null
    protected var protectedProp: String? = null
    private var privateProp: String? = null

    fun foo() {
        val a = ::publicProp
        val b = ::protectedProp
        val c = ::privateProp
    }
}

class Bar : FooB() {
    fun bar() {
        val a = ::publicProp
        val b = ::protectedProp
    }
}
```

[Type hints from IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtcwG.png)

Comment: That is very interesting, I thought it may be a problem with IntelliJ, but `::protectedProp as KMutableProperty0<String?>` will throw a `ClassCastException`

Comment: [As kotlin already had problems with `protected`](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/cannot-access-protected-method-declared-in-super-class/5189) it may be best to directly post your problem on their bug report site